# Как запрашивать ввод числа до тех пор, пока оно не будет введено корректно? C#

Tags: c#

Ребята, подскажите как решить данную проблему кода. При вводе в переменную цифры, код исправно работает, но если вести букву "р", нажать пробел и так далее, Консоль выводит: "Входная строка имела неверный формат". Такой вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе буквы или чего-то другого помимо цифры, код переходил к else и снова прогонял его.

```
Console.WriteLine("Выберите ваш пол: " + "\n 1 -> М." + "\n 2 -> Ж.");              
Console.Write("Ваш выбор: ");              
int sex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
              
bool case2Continue = true;
              
while (case2Continue == true)
{                
    if (sex == 1 || sex == 2)
        case2Continue = false;                
    else
    {                  
      case2Continue = true;                  
      Console.Write("Неправильный выбор, повторите: ");                  
      sex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Типичный код для ввода до успеха выглядит так:

```
Console.Write("Введите X: ");

while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var x) && ...))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введено неверное значение! Повторите ввод: ");
}
```

Можно вынести этот код в отдельных вспомогательный класс и немного обобщить:

```
internal static ConsoleHelper
{
    public static T Read<T>(string prompt, Predicate<T>? predicate = null)
        where T : IParsable // .NET 7+
    {
        predicate ??= x => true;

        Console.Write(prompt);

        while (!(T.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var result) && predicate(x)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введено неверное значение! Повторите ввод: ");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

и использовать так:

```
var number = ConsoleHelper.Read<int>("Введите число в диапазоне 1 до 10: ", x => x is >= 1 and <= 10);
```